# Store many id in one column laravel 5

Tags: sql, select, laravel-5

```
  <select name="car_id[]">
    //for each of cars
     </select>
```

I need to store many id to one column, will it be possible to use this?

```
  table_car =  car_id | car_desc
  table_owner = id | name | car_id
```

now the table owner should store many car_id.
How it is possible on laravel 5? I am new to this thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to store many ID's to one column, you're unable to update the database schema? I would suggest reading up on Laravel 5 and Eloquent and structure the relationships correctly.

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Comment: so the best practice will be using eloquent and save like one to many relationship? how can I be able to save id on other table while adding details on the other one? @giollianosulit

Comment: You'd need to structure your database so that yes you have one-to-many or one-to-one relationships and in the migrations specify the foreign key relations. (Very broad suggestion, but it gives you an idea)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it, for this you can use **impload()** or **serialize()** functions of **PHP**.
what they do ?, using these methods you can convert a array in string and you can save it in single column.

for this ,

```
'car_id' column should be VARCHAR type..
```

Best of luck.